# Maven has been installed in Ubuntu 18.04 but fail to work, why?

Tags: java, maven-3, ubuntu-18.04

everyone, my system is Ubuntu 18.04 and now I want to use Apache Maven, It has been installed well. The `mvn --version` outputs as following:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_312, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-100-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Then I follow the guide of official website's maven-in-5-minutes to execute this commend
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false` but get this errors:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.694 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-22T17:00:24+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/rockyzhang/.m2/repository), jboss-public-repository-group (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I also searched it from google. At first, I was wonder it's about the mirror configuration issue of `settings.xml` under`/opt/apache-maven/conf`. Then I added some mirrors and repositories info in it as following but the above error still appeared.

```
<mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
    <mirror>
      <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
      <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
      <blocked>true</blocked>
    </mirror>
     <mirror>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>central-repo1</mirrorOf>
     </mirror>
     <mirror>
         <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
         <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
         <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
         <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
     </mirror>
 </mirrors>
```

I also try `mvn help:active-profiles` to check but get the similar error

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/rockyzhang/.m2/repository), jboss-public-repository-group (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public)] -> [Help 1]
```

I am a new guy and hope someone could give me some hints about the reason. I also tried `mvn dependencies:tree` but it didn't work.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as "About general computing hardware and software", please notice that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are [explicitly on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on stackoverflow.

Comment: The central is not being used, and jboss-public-repository-group does not have all "artifacts". comment all mirrors and check if it works.

Comment: Why do you like to use something different then central repository? Remove all configuration and keep the intial state. Apart from that if you like to change settings.xml create a separate one in users home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` instead of modifying the installation...